# Declaring dependency on other snap

Tags: package-management, snap

I'm trying to pack an application that was built from source, say `foo`, which contains two executables `ui` and `server`. The server in turn call another executable, say `bar`.

I could specify the parts of the snap as follows:

```
parts:
  foo-bin:
    plugin: dump
    source: path/to/local/binary

  bar-bin:
    plugin: dump
    source: https://path.to/remote-bin.tar.gz

apps:
  ui:
    command: ui

  server:
    command: server

  bar:
    command: bar
```

The problem with this is that when installing the `snap` created with the configuration above, three executables will be created:

1. foo.ui
2. foo.server
3. foo.bar

Which brings the following problems:

1. The applications cannot longer be started by running `ui` or `server` (instead the qualified name above has to be used), and this introduces inconsistencies with regard to Windows executables (the idea is that the application I'm packing should work on multiple platforms).
2. The server cannot find `bar`.

To solve this problem, I thought about creating three separate snaps: one for the ui, one for the server, and one for `bar`. However I cannot find a way to specifying dependencies between snaps (`stage-packages` does not seem to help here).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need aliases. There's a [forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/improving-the-aliases-implementation) documentation post about it.

Comment: The insights post is out of date: putting aliases in the YAML no longer works. Reference: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/improving-the-aliases-implementation .

Comment: That outdated post cost me an hour. Thanks for the update!